# filebeat ingress timestamp replace with application timestamp

Tags: filebeat

I'm using filebeat and kafka and wanted to replace ingress filebeat timestamp with application timestamp. I saw few example with logstash where can we add filter but not sure with kafka.

In this code I tried to replace timestamp but application_timestamp but its not worked due to date format. but this code worked for message field.
filebeat.yml config below

```
fields:
    application_timestamp: "2023-06-07 07:49:51.196Z"

processors:
    - timestamp:
        field: application_timestamp
        layouts:
          - '2006-01-02 15:04:05.999Z'
        test:
          - '2019-11-18 04:59:51.123Z'
```

```
processors:
    - script:
        lang: javascript
        id: replace_timestamp
        source: >
          function process(event) {
            event.Put("@timestamp", event.Get("fields.application_timestamp"));
            return [event];
          }
```

this is what I'm getting
[image]

this is what I want to achieve
[image]

Comment: Hi there, is there specific reason to filebeat?

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov No but can't change to anything else we have to achieve this with filebeat and kafka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated working filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  tags:
    - test-kafka
  paths:
    - /Users/Documents/kafka_testing/logs/test.log
  json.keys_under_root: true  
  json.add_error_key: true
  
  

output.kafka:
  # specifying filebeat to take timestamp and message fields, other wise it
  # take the lines as json and publish to kafka
  codec.format:
    string: '%{[@timestamp]} %{[message]} %{[application_time]}'

  # kafka
  # publishing to 'test' topic
  hosts: ["localhost:9092"]
  topic: 'test'
  partition.round_robin:
    reachable_only: false
  required_acks: 1
  compression: gzip
  max_message_bytes: 1000000


processors:
  - dissect:
      tokenizer: "{type:test,application_time:%{application_time}}"
      target_prefix: ""
  - timestamp:
      field: application_time
      layouts:
        - '2006-01-02 15:04:05.99'
      test:
        - '2019-11-18 04:59:51.12'
```

Result/Output :-

```
2021-06-25T19:25:30.000Z {type:test,application_time:2021-06-25 19:25:30} 2021-06-25 19:25:30
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) to achieve what you want.
In this [article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/calculating-ingest-lag-and-storing-ingest-time-in-elasticsearch-to-improve-observability), you can find a good example.

[image]

Comment: is it possible to achieve by modify filebeat config ??

Comment: I recommend using ingest pipeline, but if you want to do that operation on filebeat, I recommend using `replace` or `copy-fields` processors. 

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/copy-fields.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/replace-fields.html

Note: You cannot use `copy-fields`  processor to replace an existing field. If the target field already exists, you must drop or rename the field before using copy_fields.